# PHP/CI pass SQL Query to an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a list of groups in a SQL query and would like them to be output to an array so that it can be referenced later on.

Currently I have the following code which loops through the groups and puts them in to the `$test_array`:

```
$test_array = array();
$query = $this->site_model->list_groups();
foreach($query as $r1) :
    $test_array[] = $r1->group_name;
endforeach;
```

This shows the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Group 1
    [1] => Group 2
    [2] => Group 3
    [3] => Group 4
    [4] => Group 5
    [5] => Group 6
    [6] => Group 7
    [7] => Group 8
)
```

What I would like is for the same query to pass to an array like below, with the intention of adding other segments to the array later on:

```
Array
(
    [Round 1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Group 1
        [1] => Group 2
        [2] => Group 3
        [3] => Group 4
        [4] => Group 5
        [5] => Group 6
        [6] => Group 7
        [7] => Group 8
    )
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$test_array = array('Round 1' => array());
...
$test_array['Round 1'][] = $r1->group_name;
```